# How to switch off TLSv1.3 in gatling?

Tags: ssl, gatling

I recently migrated from Gatling 3.3.1 to Gatling 3.4.0.
As a result, everything works fine in my local machine, but crashes in k8s because of the following error:

```
    Couldn't execute warm up request https://gatling.io
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TLSv1.3
    at sun.security.ssl.ProtocolVersion.valueOf(ProtocolVersion.java:187)
    at sun.security.ssl.ProtocolList.convert(ProtocolList.java:84)
    at sun.security.ssl.ProtocolList.<init>(ProtocolList.java:52)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.setEnabledProtocols(SSLEngineImpl.java:2081)
    ...
```

I migrated back to the working version.
I assumed from [here](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3927), that TLSv1.3 is switched on by default.
I searched for the appropriate setting in gatling-defaults.conf, but did not succeed.
I use Java 1.8 both locally and on remote k8s

Please help me to resolve this issue!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In order to support TLSv3, Gatling needs:

- either to be able to load `netty-tcnative` (basically BoringSSL)
- or run on Java 11+ where TLSv3 is available

We can see in the logs that the former fails. We can also see that `netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64` can't be loaded while `netty_transport_native_epoll_x86` can. This means you're running on a 32-bit Linux. `netty-tcnative`/BoringSSL is only available on 64-bit.

The latter fails as you stated running on Java 8.

We can probably improve things on our side, but you should switch to a 64-bit host.

Otherwise, you can enforce the list of supported protocols in `gatling.conf`, see https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf#L57

Comment: Hello Stephane! I did not disable SSL. The only think I did is to raise versions:
gatling 3.3.1 -> 3.4.0
gatling maven plugin 3.0.5 -> 3.1.0
scala maven plugin 4.3.1 -> 4..0

Comment: Could you please provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Also, are you running on ARM?

Comment: Hello Stephane! I run tests locally on Mac and remotely on some linux server

Comment: Again, could you please provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: I've edited my answer and explained why TLSv3 is not available for you.

Comment: Thank you Stephane! Now the situation is clear. I actually understood the problem with websocket also. I forgot to place .exitHereIfFailed after validating the message from websocket. The new Gatling behaves in a different way than 3.3.1, but the problem was in my script.

Thanks once more!

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with your old version of java try this

**enabledProtocols = [TLSv1.2]**             # Array of enabled protocols for HTTPS, if empty use Netty's defaults

Answer (score -1):

Adding this line in gatling.conf fixed it for me.  I'm using Gatling 3.1.0 and Java 8.

```
gatling.ssl.useOpenSsl=false
```

Comment: Extremely outdated version and hence outdated advice to. You should upgrade instead. The current version is 3.9.5.

Comment: Not everyone is able to upgrade due to company limitations.  This answer might help others in the same position.